# Why does Electron kill Windows processes that have arguments with colons?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, process, electron

If I start an Electron program that has an argument with a colon, the program immediately exits.

```
Process process = new Process();
process.StartInfo.FileName = "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\SomeElectronApp.exe";
process.StartInfo.Arguments = "ab:c d";
process.Start();

process.WaitForExit();
Console.WriteLine(1); // break point here
```

However, if I swap the arguments such that the one with the colon always comes last, then the program starts successfully.

This is mentioned [here](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/25270):

> [This] is a security mitigation against an age old windows flaw

Does anyone have insight into what this flaw is?

Update:

Found the source code [here](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/462de5f97a302987dc5fa5c222781ceed040f390/shell/app/command_line_args.cc#L46):

The function `CheckCommandLineArguments` has the logic:

```
else if (IsUrlArg(argv[i])) {
   block_args = true;
}
```

Where `IsUrlArg` does:

```
// colon indicates that the argument starts with a URI scheme
if (c == ':') {
     // it could also be a Windows filesystem path
     if (p == arg + 1)
          break;

     return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer from looking at the commit.

It was done to fix a remote code execution vulnerability (CVE-2018-1000006). [Source](https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-w222-53c6-c86p):

> Affected versions of electron may be susceptible to a remote code execution flaw when certain conditions are met:

> 1. The electron application is running on Windows.
> 2. The electron application registers as the default handler for a protocol, such as nodeapp://.

> This vulnerability is caused by a failure to sanitize additional arguments to chromium in the command line handler for Electron.

[blog post here](https://www.electronjs.org/blog/protocol-handler-fix)

Answer (score 1):

The "flaw" is most likely unquoted filenames containing whitespace.

Consider

```
> "C:\Program Files (x86)\SomeElectronApp.exe" "C:\Program Files (x86)\SomeElectronFile.dat"
```

vs

```
> "C:\Program Files (x86)\SomeElectronApp.exe" C:\Program Files (x86)\SomeElectronFile.dat
```

or

```
> C:\Program Files (x86)\SomeElectronApp.exe C:\Program Files (x86)\SomeElectronFile.dat
```

If by mistake you have set up a file association as

```
path\to\exe %1
```

instead of

```
path\to\exe "%1"
```

then every program using the `ShellExecute` function will pass you an unquoted filename, even if it contains whitespace.

The thing that makes it a "windows" flaw is that on Windows, a single command-line string is passed to the spawned program, which is responsible for breaking it up into the `argv` array.  In contrast most other OSes pass an argument array, so the launching program has to go to some effort to break filenames into multiple words.

Comment: I found the actual source code that does this (in my question). Seems like they actually allow windows file paths, but not other arguments that have a colon, so even the unquoted file path would pass the check. Seems like they're trying to prevent URIs?