# Electron Windows Production Bundle Command Line Arguments

Tags: windows, electron, command-line-arguments, electron-builder

I'm building an Electron App using `electron-builder` on macOS.

In my code I access the command line args like this:

```
const cmd = electron.remote.app.commandLine;

const val = cmd.hasSwitch('myArg')
        ? cmd.getSwitchValue('myArg')
        : undefined;
```

This works fine for the production build on macOS when providing the arguments:

```
./my-electron-app.app/Contents/MacOS/my-electron-app --myArg=foo

// or:
open my-electron-app.app --args -myArg=foo
```

But on Windows I can't get it working.

Here's what I tried using `cmd.exe`:

```
my-electron-app.exe --myArg=foo
my-electron-app.exe -myArg=foo
my-electron-app.exe /myArg=foo
my-electron-app.exe myArg=foo
```

When logging `electron.remote.process.argv[1]` I can see the passed arguments on macOS **and** Windows, **but** `hasSwitch` and `getSwitchValue` won't give me the value.

What am I doing wrong? Or is there a better way to get cross platform command line arguments working?

Comment: at first, this told me that you might be passing a URL/path like argument which gets stripped in Windows, and was going to ask about the specific arg (see [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66158085/why-does-electron-kill-windows-processes-that-have-arguments-with-colons)), but I would have expected that arg to be stripped from process.argv as well.. so I guess it's something else

Comment: I just tried on my Windows machine, passing in `"-abc=foo"` into VSCode's launch.json "args" property, and `app.commandLine.hasSwitch("abc")` correctly returned true. I'm not using electron builder anywhere. Not sure if that's relevant. I'm not running a packaged version of my app to, just from source.

Comment: it's not [this](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/26257), is it? Seems similar though not sure why it would work on Mac

Comment: @pushkin Thanks for the comment. Yes, I want to pass a path as argument (`C:\...`), **but** passing a string  like `foo` won't work as well. I just checked it again `my-electron-app.exe -myArg=foo` will show `-myArg=foo` in `electron.remote.process.argv`. `...` I just did some additional debugging, with the following results: `hasSwitch('myArg`)` returns `false`, and `getSwitchValue('myArg')` returns `""`. I tried all 4 versions from above: double/single dash, slash, no prefix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm gonna take a guess that this is because of the capital letters in your switch. See [this](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/26257) closed issue:

> This is intentional. The `hasSwitch` API is a direct wrapper of the Chromium CommandLine class, which behaves this way on purpose.

From [Chromium source](https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/master:base/command_line.h;l=145;drc=036150cfca14e4f91b7f06855b19462575aed37f):

> Switch names must be lowercase.

Though it's not totally clear to me yet why Mac doesn't suffer from the same problem.

Comment: Thanks! I'll try using all lowercase and will report back

Comment: That did the trick! When using all lowercase it works perfectly. Seems like Chromium even doesn't really care if you use double-dash, single-dash or slash in front of the argument. I guess using dashes within the switch name is also allowed, but I haven't tested it.