# Electron App not starting with command line arguments

Tags: node.js, electron, command-line-arguments

I have a simple app in Electron. In the `main.js` I wait for the event `whenReady` and then I wanna read the command line arguments.

```
const createWindow = () => {
  const win = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    //show: false,
  });

  win.webContents.openDevTools();
  win.setMenu(null);
  win.loadFile("index.html");

  return win;
};

app.whenReady().then(async () => {
  console.log(process.argv);
  createWindow();
})
```

If I run the app (on dev with `electron .` or build with `myapp.exe` in terminal) it works fine. The app starts and the window are visible.
But if I start the app with more than one command line args it does not start anymore. No part (whenReady) or something will called. Nothing.

#### This WORKS

```
electron . path="c:\data\test.txt"
```

#### This works NOT

```
electron . path="c:\data\test.txt" user="Name" pass="secret"
```

I remember: Both, dev and the build `.exe` app not starting. No logs, no error, no Window.

And it makes no difference if I use other variables with or without double quotes, or if I use a minus like this `-path=xxx`. Nothing will starting the app.

Can anywhere help?

Comment: Does the process exit immediately (you could verify this using a command line)? Could you try and insert `--` (with spaces before and after) after the period and see if that exhibits the same problem? For me, both work though.

Comment: This works. But why? Is not a good user experience if you need to add " -- " before the args I mean...

Comment: Well, because Electron can also take arguments (run `electron` and you'll get a usage guide). Using `--` is a convention to signal programs that what follows is input, rather than options they should try to parse. In the case of NodeJS, Electron, ... this will cause the launching program to pass these arguments to the launched program. However, I find it especially strange that I cannot reproduce your problem.

Comment: I believe the path has to go last. I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66158085/why-does-electron-kill-windows-processes-that-have-arguments-with-colons) is somewhat related. Electron has some checks that will see the colon in the path and error out basically